# Knockout.js not updating value of observable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm having trouble getting Knockout to update the value of my observable.

Model:

```
function AppViewModel() {
   var self = this;
   self.observable = ko.observable();
   self.test = function() {
       self.observable("test")
   }
};
var model = new AppViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

View:

```
<p>Value of observable: <input data-bind="value: $root.observable()" /></p>
<p>The value is: <span data-bind="text: $root.observable()"></span></p>
```

When I type text into the input field, it should update the value of my observable to what I've typed, correct? But the 2nd paragraph doesn't update its text accordingly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the parentheses in your bindings.  You want to bind to the observable itself, not the value the observable is holding.

```
<p>Value of observable: <input data-bind="value: $root.observable" /></p>
<p>The value is: <span data-bind="text: $root.observable"></span></p>
```

Comment: FYI: `<span data-bind="text: $root.observable()"></span>` is perfectly  acceptable. It's the `input` binding that needs to work directly with the observable.